Tableau Take max year value in a table
I have the following data in tableau



Year
Values




2021
202


2022
212


2023
100


2024
280



What i want is the Year Max values in this case 280 and i want it to be dynamic so that when the Year change to 2025 it should pick the latest values
I wrote SUM(Values) = {MAX(Year)}
It is giving an error.
Any help guys

I got it at the end using the code below
IF [Year] = {MAX([Year])} = True
THEN [Values]
ELSE 0
end


You don't need the " = True" part.

And in most cases you can remove the "ELSE 0" part also -- since aggregation functions like SUM() ignore null values and the default is equivalent to "ELSE NULL"
